# Having only 5 elements per XML component python

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7

I have python 2.7 code that appends to an XML file every time there is a new server version number (essectially keeping a log of all the version numbers). The only problem with this is that the XML file is getting too large, which will, eventually, slow the script down. I only want to keep the last 5 version numbers? Is there a way to delete the last `history` tag and add the new one to the front? A skeleton of my XML file is below:

```
 <gateway id="" url="">
            <component id="">
            <history time="0" version="0" />
            <history pretty="" sourceUrl="" time="" version="" /></component>
            <component id="">
            <history time="0" version="0" />
            <history pretty="" sourceUrl="" time="" version="" /></component>
            <component id="">
            <history time="0" version="0" />
            <history pretty="" sourceUrl="" time="" version="" /></component>
            <component id="">
            <history time="0" version="0" />
            <history pretty="" sourceUrl="" time="" version="" /></component>
            <component id="">
            <history time="0" version="0" />
            <history pretty="" sourceUrl="" time="" version="" /></component>
            <component id="">
            <history time="0" version="0" />
            <history pretty="" sourceUrl="" time="" version="" /></component>
            <component id="">
            <history time="0" version="0" />
            <history pretty="" time="" version="" /></component>
            <component id="">
            <history time="0" version="0" />
            </component>
    </gateway>
```

Comment: Not really that straightforward - you will have to open the file, parse the XML, update the tree/DOM/whatever and write it back out

Comment: @jonrsharpe I think, that what you described is exactly what heinst asked for. His xml is not too large, just 5 history elements expected, so it shall not be so bad. If someone (you?) provide code snippet, doing this, heinst would be happier (but tuturials for `lxml` or builtin Python `xml.etree` or whatever are available too)

Comment: @JanVlcinsky if you could point me to a tutorial or something where they have a max number of elements in the XML file I'd happily read that. I just don't know how to go about only keeping 5 `<history>` tags for each `<component>`

Comment: The tutorials are providing explanation, how to manipulate the document, but not how to limit number of records. I will write an answer for you.

Comment: @heinst Sorry, I give up, it is a bit too much coding for this moment. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this code should work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import itertools

tree = ET.parse('gateway.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

MAX_VERSIONS = 5

for component in root:
    counter = itertools.count()
    histories = sorted((history.attrib.get("version", 0), counter, history)
                       for history in component if history.tag == "history")
    if len(histories) <= MAX_VERSIONS:  # Nothing to remove
        continue
    remove_histories = histories[:-MAX_VERSIONS]  # These should be removed
    for v, c, history in remove_histories:
        component.remove(history)

tree.write('output.xml')
```

It iterates through all gateways, and creates a list of all history entries in, stored as tuples:

```
(version, counter, Element)
```

I added a counter to differentiate if all versions numbers happen to be the same. 
Then I sort, remove the last 5 entries from this list, and then remove every History entry that is still in this list from the XML file. Finally I write the output XML file.

Answer (score 0):

I'll actually throw on here how I did it. I think its cleaner and more of a simplistic solution, but Zweedeend definitely pointed me in the right direction.

```
for gateway in root.findall('gateway'):
    for component in gateway.findall('component'):
        firstCounter = 0
        for history in sorted(component.findall('history'), key=lambda h:h.attrib['time']):
            if firstCounter < 5:
                firstCounter = firstCounter + 1
            else:
                component.remove(history)
```